# Uploading file to flask app gives NotADirectoryError: [Errno 20] Not a directory

Tags: python, html, azure, flask

He there,
I have have been trying to find a solution to my problem for 2 days now but still have not found anything. Might just be missing it.
My flask web app is run on Microsoft azure. The error is very simple discretionary not found but i don't know how to find out what the right path is.

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2069, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2054, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2051, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1501, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1499, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1485, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
  File "/home/ivar/PycharmProjects/Course8.1/app.py", line 78, in genpanel
    f.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/werkzeug/datastructures.py", line 3013, in save
    dst = open(dst, "wb")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/uploads/GenPanelOverzicht_DG-3.1.0_HAN.xlsx'
```

I have the following flask code:

```
import os

from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename

UPLOAD_FOLDER = '/uploads'
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER
FLASK_DEBUG=1
@app.route('/')
def home():
    """ home page """
    return render_template("basis.html")
@app.route('/genpanel', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def genpanel():
    """ genpanel upload page """
    print(os.getcwd())
    try:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            f = request.files['file']
            filename = secure_filename(f.filename)
            f.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
            md5sum, dictionary = Genpanelanalyser.fileopener(
                '/uploads/'+f.filename)
            md5sumold = Genpanelanalyser.getmd5sum()
            if md5sum != md5sumold:
                Genpanelanalyser.database(md5sum, dictionary)
                message = "File upload was successfull"
                os.remove('/uploads/' + f.filename)
                return render_template("genpanel.html", message=message)
            else:
                message = "Data allready exists"
                os.remove('/uploads/'+f.filename)
                return render_template("genpanel.html", message=message)
        else:
            message = "Upload a file"
            return render_template("genpanel.html", message=message)
    except FileExistsError or FileNotFoundError:
        message = "File not found"
        return render_template("genpanel.html", message=message)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

This is my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="Danielle Dunnewold, Ivar van den Akker en Moshtach
    Ismail" >
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Manual</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/Style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <!-- horizontaal menu -->
    <div class="scrollmenu">
        <a href="/">HOME</a>
        <a href="/results">APPLICATION</a>
        <a href="/manual">MANUAL</a>
        <a href="/download">DOWNLOAD RESULTS</a>
        <a href="/genpanel">UPLOAD GENEPANEL</a>
    </div>
<H2>Upload a new genepanel</H2>
    <form action = '/genpanel' method = "POST" enctype = "multipart/form-data">
         <input type = "file" name = "file" />
         <input type = "submit" value = "Submit" />
    </form>
    <br>
    <p>{{ message }}</p>
</body>
</html>
```

If someone knows a solution or a page where i can find a solution or a way to find a solution feel free to comment and help me out. If any more information is needed i can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

upload folder is defined as  `app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER`, but does seems like it exist, so the line of code  `f.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))` is getting failed. you can try

1. create the folder "uploads", and it will be at the same level as templates.
2. the os.remove will look like as below(remove the first /)

```
os.remove('uploads/' + f.filename)
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a function to get the path to the upload folder and pass it on to my function so the path would always be correct. I tried to create the folder but that didn't realy work out. You where right about the /.

function for getting the path:

```
import  os
def getpath():
    patht = os.getcwd()
    path = patht+"/uploads/"
    return path
```

New function in app.py:

```
UPLOAD_FOLDER = uploads.getpath.getpath()
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER


@app.route('/')
def home():
    """ home page """
    return render_template("basis.html")
@app.route('/genpanel', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def genpanel():
    """ genpanel upload page """
    try:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            f = request.files['file']
            filename = secure_filename(f.filename)
            f.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
            md5sum, dictionary = Genpanelanalyser.fileopener(
                UPLOAD_FOLDER+f.filename)
            md5sumold = Genpanelanalyser.getmd5sum()
            if md5sum != md5sumold:
                Genpanelanalyser.database(md5sum, dictionary)
                message = "File upload was successfull"
                os.remove(UPLOAD_FOLDER+f.filename)
                return render_template("genpanel.html", message=message)
            else:
                message = "Data allready exists"
                os.remove(UPLOAD_FOLDER+f.filename)
                return render_template("genpanel.html", message=message)
        else:
            message = "Upload a file"
            return render_template("genpanel.html", message=message)
    except FileExistsError or FileNotFoundError:
        message = "File not found"
        return render_template("genpanel.html", message=message)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```